# Numpy: can't assign a matrix to a submatrix

Tags: python, numpy

Here's what happens:

```
>>> A = np.vander(range(3))
>>> A
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [4, 2, 1]])
>>> Q = householder(A[1:, [1]])
>>> Q
array([[-0.4472136 , -0.89442719],
       [-0.89442719,  0.4472136 ]])
>>> X = np.dot(Q, A[1:, 1:])
>>> X
array([[-2.23606798e+00, -1.34164079e+00],
       [ 2.22044605e-16, -4.47213595e-01]])
>>> A[1:, 1:] = X
>>> A
array([[ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 1, -2, -1],
       [ 4,  0,  0]])
```

This is driving me mad. What's happening here? Why doesn't `A[1:, 1:]` equal `X`?

Comment: `A` is dtype `int`.

Comment: IOW, ^^ `A = np.vander(range(3)).astype(float)` and your code works.